# A better alternative to using a long series of "if/else if" statements in C?

Tags: c, if-statement

Originally I used switch/case, but the condition had to be a constant value that the variable would match, versus a boolean of whether the variable was within the range.

Instead, I have this monstrosity:

```
    if ( data[y] > 91 ) {
       grades[9] = grades[9] + 1;
    }
    else if ( data[y] > 88 && data[y] < 92 ) {
        grades[8] = grades[8] + 1;
    }
    else if ( data[y] > 84 && data[y] < 89 ) {
        grades[7] = grades[7] + 1;
    }
    else if ( data[y] > 81 && data[y] < 85) {
        grades[6] = grades[6] + 1;
    }
    else if ( data[y] > 79 && data[y] < 82) {
        grades[5] = grades[5] + 1;
    }
    else if ( data[y] > 74 && data[y] < 79 ) {
        grades[4] = grades[4] + 1;
    }
    else if ( data[y] > 71 && data[y] < 75 ) {
        grades[3] = grades[3] + 1;
    }
    else if ( data[y] > 68 && data[y] < 72 ) {
        grades[2] = grades[2] + 1;
    }
    else if ( data[y] > 59 && data[y] < 69 ) {
        grades[1] = grades[1] + 1;
    else {
        //data[y] < 60:
        grades[0] = grades[0] + 1;
    }
```

Does anybody know a nicer way to handle this block of code, since my switch/case idea can't apply? Surely there has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: A switch could totally apply.  Or a table.  Or if you're daring and document it, you might be able to group much of this in a single equation.  `gradeno = data[y]/3.5-25` gets you close.

Comment: If you're only writing for GCC you could actually use `case 92 .. 100: ...; break; case 88 .. 91: ...; break;` etc.

Comment: @MooingDuck You sure that this formular is correct?

Comment: Sure.  Code in RPG.  It implements what is, in effect, a "come from" statement.

Comment: FWIW ... In your example code above you don't need the second condition within each else if.

Comment: 1) Use a switch.  2) Set a `gradeNum` variable in the switch block and then do `grades[gradeNum] = grades[gradeNum] + 1;` after the end of the switch block.

Comment: If performance is an issue you can actually combine, say, ooga's answer with a binary search, i.e. start with the `(data[y] >= 80)` to cut the search space in half.

Comment: Why are these numbers significant? Can you (e.g.) change the numbers slightly and just do something like (e.g.) `grades[ (data[y] - 50)/5 ]++`?

Comment: The numbers are significant to my personal project because I have to tally the spread of data within each range; they're only significant to me in this specific circumstance.

Comment: @Rohawk: Sometimes the simplest solution is to redefine the problem - if the numbers are only significant to you, then you only need a minor change to "you".. ;-)

Comment: Asking a question of "how can I do A if B?" and getting an answer of "well if you change B, you can do ___" isn't redefining the problem, it's avoiding the original question because your solution doesn't work for it.  Not helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a loop. You'll also need an array of the minimum data value for each grade. Here's some untested code as an example:

```
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (data[y] >= minDataValueForGrade[i])
    {
        grades[i]++;
        break;
    }
}
```

It's short, easy to read, and makes it really easy to change the values that correspond to each grade.

Comment: Ill just add that according to his example code, the loop should be reversed (from 9 to 0), since if grades[0] represents the lowest category the condition would be true for every item and only increment grades[0].

Answer (score 15):

The most obvious to shorten your code is to get rid of the unnecessary second tests:

```
if      (data[y] >= 92) ++grades[9];
else if (data[y] >= 89) ++grades[8];
else if (data[y] >= 85) ++grades[7];
else if (data[y] >= 82) ++grades[6];
else if (data[y] >= 80) ++grades[5];
else if (data[y] >= 75) ++grades[4];
else if (data[y] >= 72) ++grades[3];
else if (data[y] >= 69) ++grades[2];
else if (data[y] >= 60) ++grades[1];
else                    ++grades[0];
```

Answer (score 6):

This seems like a sensible data-driven approach:

```
int grade_cutoff[] = { 59, 68, 71, 74, 79, 81, 84, 88, 91, INT_MAX };
int grade_bucket;

for (grade_bucket = 0; data[y] > grade_cutoff[grade_bucket]; grade_bucket++) {
  /* nothing */
}

grades[grade_bucket]++;
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use a simple lookup table:

```
const unsigned int index[] = { 1, 1, /* ... */, 2, 2, /* ... */ };

++grades[data[y] < 60 ? 0 : index[data[y]]];
```

Comment: Wouldn't `index[]` need to be like, 40 integers wide for this solution to work?

Comment: @jucestain: yes, but you get an O(1) lookup that takes an amount of time independent of the value of `data[y]`. You already have lots of data, so the data-vs-code trade-off is already swinging towards the data end. Why not go all the way? Of course the code-solution becomes more attractive as the interval lenghts get longer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the long serie of `if .. else` what about:

```
int arr[] = {60, 69, 72, 75, 79, 82, 85, 89, 92};
int i = 0;

while (i < sizeof arr/ sizeof *arr && data[y] < arr[i] && i++);

grades[i]++;
```

Comment: Makes for concise code. But this solution is not very readable. I'm guessing this is for a homework assignment.

Comment: @baph0mt I totally agree

Comment: This is how a pro would do it. ***Impressive. Very nice.***

Comment: @Igor I'm trying to answer the question to go without the long serie of `if .. else`. Otherwise my preference in real life is @ooga solution.

Comment: @ouah Every pro, including me prefers your solution because it is more instructive. I get so many newcomers looking just for the solution not actually understanding the code which can be harmful when they work with me.

Answer (score 0):

My `C` is rusty, to be truthful, however, you might consider looking at the problem from a different perspective than a conditional.

You should (I think) be able to restructure your data so that you could implement the decision logic without (or with much less) conditionals. I'm thinking something like a 2 dimensional array or a lookup table. Something along those lines....

Comment: My ability to write C is rusty; but I can (and did) answer conceptually. My answer now appears to be echoed by @hobbs. I imagine we were writing at the same time despite my post coming in 1 minute earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
int const datum = data[y];
int const index = (datum > 59) + (datum > 68) + (datum > 71)
    + (datum > 74) + (datum > 79) + (datum > 81)
    + (datum > 84) + (datum > 88) + (datum > 91);
++ grades[index];
```

Just calculate the index.

Answer (score 0):

For a radical variation on the theme, assuming marks can only be in the range 0..100, consider creating an array which contains the grade number for the score:

```
enum { MAX_SCORE = 100 };
static const int upper_bound[] = { 60, 69, 72, 75, 80, 82, 85, 89, 92, MAX_SCORE+1 };
enum { N_BOUNDS = sizeof(upper_bound) / sizeof(upper_bound[0]) };
int grade_for_score[MAX_SCORE + 1];

int score = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N_BOUNDS; i++)
{
    while (score < upper_bound[i])
        grade_for_score[score++] = i;
}
```

The compensation for the setup work is that processing a score is trivial:

```
assert(data[y] >= 0 && data[y] <= MAX_SCORE);
grades[grade_for_score[data[y]]++;
```

This might be a benefit because it doesn't require any conditionals to process the grades as they come in, beyond the basic validation that the score is in the range [0..MAX_SCORE].  It does use some data space, of course.  Of course, if the data is being read from a file (or a database), the I/O interaction time completely swamps the grading time, and the optimization is essentially pointless.

Working code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* Setup */
    enum { MAX_SCORE = 100 };
    static const int upper_bound[] = { 60, 69, 72, 75, 80, 82, 85, 89, 92, MAX_SCORE+1 };
    enum { N_BOUNDS = sizeof(upper_bound) / sizeof(upper_bound[0]) };
    int grade_for_score[MAX_SCORE + 1];

    int score = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N_BOUNDS; i++)
    {
        while (score < upper_bound[i])
            grade_for_score[score++] = i;
    }

    /* Scoring - test each score from [0..MAX_SCORE] */
    int grades[N_BOUNDS] = { 0, };
    int data[1];
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_SCORE; i++)
    {
        data[y] = i;
        assert(data[y] >= 0 && data[y] <= MAX_SCORE);
        grades[grade_for_score[data[y]]]++;
    }

    /* Print grades */
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N_BOUNDS; i++)
    {
        sum += grades[i];
        printf("Grade %d: %3d (cumulative %3d)\n", i, grades[i], sum);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that it would be possible to initialize the `grade_for_score` table at compile time instead of doing it at run time:

```
/* Manually generated; not formally checked for correctness */
int grade_for_score[] =
{
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,
    2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,
    5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,
    8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,
    9
};
```

However, the table is easily computed from the table of upper bounds, and computers are better at getting the counting right than humans, so it is better to create the table at runtime.

Example run:

```
Grade 0:  60 (cumulative  60)
Grade 1:   9 (cumulative  69)
Grade 2:   3 (cumulative  72)
Grade 3:   3 (cumulative  75)
Grade 4:   5 (cumulative  80)
Grade 5:   2 (cumulative  82)
Grade 6:   3 (cumulative  85)
Grade 7:   4 (cumulative  89)
Grade 8:   3 (cumulative  92)
Grade 9:   9 (cumulative 101)
```